# JS Syntax error Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Not able to figure out the mistake here. Can someone help figure it out.

```
$('.label-visibility').append("<a href="' +externalLink["externalLinkLabel"]+ '" style="color:blue;">'+externalLink["externalLinkLabel"]+'</a>");
```

Comment: What exactly is inside `externalLink["externalLinkLabel"]` ?

Comment: You've got quote character problems.

Comment: externalLink is an array var externalLink = {};

Comment: [Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) might help you avoid these types of syntax errors.

Comment: yea some quotes issue looks like but I made sure everything is correct.

Comment: *externalLink is an array var externalLink = {};*  That's not an array, it's an object. Javascript has no associative arrays, only indexed.

Comment: Oh, thanks for clarifying that. Also inspite of fixing the error, my <a> anchor tag is not working the way it is expected to work. can I do something like this ?  - var label = $("<p id='title'><a href="' + externalLink["externalLinkLabel"] + '" style=\"color:blue;\"></a></p>"); ? This throws me an error as well. Can you suggest alternatives to display my link inside my <p> tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
style="color:blue;"
```

to

```
style=\"color:blue;\"
```

You cannot use unescaped `"` inside `"`.

**There's many more quoting errors in your code**, all of which I hopefully fixed:

```
$('.label-visibility').append(
  '<a href="'  
  + externalLink["externalLinkLabel"]
  + '" style=\"color:blue;\">'
  + externalLink["externalLinkLabel"]
  +'</a>');
```

Btw, this is one of the reasons the people creating Javascript have given us **[template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)**:

```
$('.label-visibility').append(
  `<a href="${externalLink['externalLinkLabel']}"
      style="color:blue;">${externalLink["externalLinkLabel"]}
  </a>`);
```

Comment: It worked !! Cool! thanks @connexo